# Solar panel powered regulated output voltage collapses after short run-time

Tags: motor, pwm

I have a [PWM DC motor controller](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Width-Modulation-12V-40V-10A-Pulse-PWM-DC-Motor-Speed-Control-Switch-New-Free-Shipping/32608514172.html?spm=2114.01010208.0.501.XqbcRh) for a water pump.

Input voltage 24 V large solar panel (the ones you get on houses).

The PWM has a L7812 so outputs 12 V max.

Pump 12 V, 0.9 A.

Everything starts fine, but after a short while the voltage and amps drop to nothing.

I have tested it on a 12 V, 3 mA PC fan with a regulated power supply, and the same thing happens.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: make a schematic. Without one, your question is unclear.

Comment: Are you sure that the second fan isn't 0.3A instead of 3mA (that is 0.003A... very small for a fan)?  Suspect that your solar panel is probably getting hot.  It gets less efficient as it warms up and this sounds like that sort of issue.  Not confident enough to post as an answer, though.  Check the output voltage of the panel.

Answer (score 1):

0.9 A through an L7812 feeding from 24 V gives a loss of (24-12)*0.9 = 10.8 W.

All of this will be converted to heat in your small package (presumably TO-220 or some variant thereof), and this is *a lot*. It will get very hot, and then it will shut down as to protect itself from self destruction.

Your fan is not 3 mA, it is 300 mA. This is less than 900 mA but still a lot of power.

It is possible that you can attach a *big* heat sink to the L7812 and make this work, but a better option is to buy a cheap switch-mode converter.

Comment: So with my 12v power supply and the fan:

Comment: So with my 12v power supply and the fan setup: 12*0.3=3.6W and it slows to a stop. The amps drop from .3 to .15 stays there fore a few minutes then gradually fades to zero.  For my main setup with a solar panel I have fans connected directly to it to cool the motor controller, these keep working as normal.